# Sum columns by year

Tags: r, dplyr

How Do I sum up all the values in 'exports' and 'imports' of all countries by year?

data frame :

| Country | Year | exports | imports |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Denmark | 2004 | 10000000 | 10000000 |
| Denmark | 2008 | 20000000 | 20000000 |
| Denmark | 2009 | 30000000 | 30000000 |
| Norway | 2004 | 10000000 | 10000000 |
| Norway | 2008 | 20000000 | 20000000 |
| Norway | 2009 | 10000000 | 30000000 |

I tried:

```
df_frame %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarize(
    total_exports = sum(exports),
    total_imports = sum(imports)
  )
```

But I got:

| Year | exports | imports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2004 | NA | NA |
| 2008 | NA | NA |
| 2009 | NA | NA |

I want:

| Year | exports | imports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2004 | 40000000 | 20000000 |
| 2008 | 40000000 | 40000000 |
| 2009 | 20000000 | 60000000 |

Comment: Your code works. Maybe restart your environment?

Comment: I'm still getting the same thing

Answer (score 0):

We could group and then use `summarise` with `across`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(across(-Country, sum))
```

```
   Year  exports  imports
  <int>    <int>    <int>
1  2004 20000000 20000000
2  2008 40000000 40000000
3  2009 40000000 60000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `sum()` function and your data.frame has missing values  (e.g. `NA`), you have to pass the argument `na.rm = TRUE` in the `sum()` function call. Then your code above will work.